# Hybrid configuration in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration-files

I have an application where there is some profile specific header properties and some common header properties and these are maintained in **application.yml** file. I want to use these in a way so that when any spring profile like ut/pd is specified then it picks up the profile specific email but other properties from a default/common section. The problem I'm trying to overcome is repeating the properties when they already exist in common section.

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: ERROR
    com.martin.client: DEBUG

spring:
  profiles:
    active: "default"
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"

header:
  header-key: SHA-256
  mac-algorith: HmacSHA256
  email: aaa@test.com
  secret-key: 692e9d385fbe74cf2a02049f4ee5e31df5296266
  mac: HmacSHA256
  secret: hmac-sha256
  gws-env: aaa

---

spring:
  profiles: ut

header:
  email: bbb@test.com
  gws-env: bbb

---

spring:
  profiles: pd

header:
  email: ccc@test.com
  gws-env: bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of the common properties within `application.properties` and all of the profile specific properties within `application-{profile}.properties`.

**application.properties**

```
my.default.prop=hello
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
my.custom.prop=world
```

Spring Boot will look at both files.  You can even override default properties within the profile specific property file as well.